# Comment system breaks upon opening a new browser tab

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have sort of design problem with my site. **Here's the introduction:**

I have a simple, dynamic page which contains a videoplayer and next to it a bunch of videos to play. Under the videoplayer there's a comment section that is powered with [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) because naturally I don't want the page to refresh and reset the video if someone enters a comment while watching.

So, the page fetches the video ID to play via a $_GET variable and then gets another 10 or so video links based on the ID from MySQL database and plays the first one and lists the rest as links next to the player.

The comment system is simple. It fetches all the comments from MySQL table having the same ID as the video playing and lists them via the jquery form plugin mentioned before. Upon entering a new comment it adds the comment to the table again by targeting the same ID.

Since the ajax form plugin fetches the comments from external PHP files containing the comment showing/adding code - I have to use a $_SESSION variable to pass the info from the main page to those files.

**And here's the problem:**

Everything works as I expected when a client browses the page normally.. but when he decides to open another video to a new tab - the comment system breaks down.

So what happens is that I pass the video ID from the main page's $_GET variable to a $_SESSION variable and use it to let the external show/add-comments-PHP-files know which comments to show. This works fine when a client is using only one tab but when he opens another video in a new tab the $_SESSION variable of course updates to match the new tab's currently playing video's comments and since this variable is same in both tabs - the original tab now points wrongly to the new tab's comments.

So.. to hopefully clarify a bit:

> **browser tab 1:**
>
> $_SESSION['now_playing'] = video 1
>
> [..client opens another video into a 2nd tab]
>
> **browser tab 2:**
>
> $_SESSION['now_playing'] = video 2
>
> ..and from this point on the tab 1's comments are of course the same
>   as tab 2's.

Would there be any tricks to start a new session upon a new tab creation or something like that? I'm rather new to all this so there might be obviously silly involved.. any pointers how to get this fixed would be greatly appreciated - even if it's a better way to implement the commenting - adding comments without a page refresh is a must tho.

Regards, kitsu

Comment: Thinking that you might be able to add a hidden field. Once the page loads set its value to the session variable. And point your jquery values to the hidden field instead of the session var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting the classic problem that the Session data is controlled by a cookie, and is therefore per browser not per screen.

One approach is to have a hidden field on the screen.  When handling the get to create the screen, set this to a unique value, and use that value as a key into the session data.

Then pass the value back with the ajax requests - so each screen's requests are handled with a different part of the session data.

Comment: Cheers for the answers jco and Ian! Managed to get it running as expected by using a hidden field as you suggested :-)